# How to fix "Invalid header value: must be a string or array of strings" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-passport

I have an issue on a prod server that I don't have in local. Laravel send me an error which says that there is a header issue. I think this is an Apache issue.

I work on my local machine with Mamp. Laravel is using OAuth with Laravel Passport. I've tried on my local machine and it's working. I'm running on a Apache server too.

On my production server, as soon as I want to login on my application, I have this error :

> ERROR 500 : InvalidArgumentException, Invalid header value: must be a
>   string or array of strings; cannot be an empty array.

And it's in `MessageTrait.php line 389` from Laravel Zendframwork vendor.

Maybe it's just a module on the server ?

Thanks

Comment: are there differences in the php version? which code is executed?

Comment: That's a PHP error so it has nothing to do with Apache. Have you debugged to see what the value it's trying to set is? It's most likely something else in your code that produces an invalid response, which you then are trying to set as header. Please show us all the relevant code and we can try and help you.

Comment: That's a PHP error but maybe because of a server setting. There is no special code. Here is the code : `axios.post('${baseUrl}/oauth/token', {
          grant_type: 'password',
          username: email,
          password,
          client_id: Config.oauthClientId,
          client_secret: Config.oauthClientSecret,
        })`
And it directly triggers the error. The code is working on my local computer. So I don't think that it's a PHP error.
I've seen that the header sent are different between the two environment.

Comment: It's a new project that I have to handle. I know that it was working before a server reboot. There is nothing more code triggered before. But the headers sent are different. It send a xsrf_token and laravel_session on my local, and nothing on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, my solution was to downgrade the next packages to that specific version because that was the version that was working in my project:

```
composer require symfony/http-kernel:3.4.20
composer require symfony/http-foundation:3.4.20
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge:1.1.0
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: It's what I expected ! Thanks a lot, it's working. Fortunately, there are still people who try to help and who do not speak for nothing :D !
Thanks again. Now I have to understand why it's working on my local and not on the server.. How did you figure out that it was those 3 packages is error ?

Comment: Ok, maybe it happened because you installed a package in prod server (you can check your local composer.json with prod server's composer.json )... another solution could be to put your local vendor in prod  server, I found those 3 packages becouse  i was needing to install a package (neoxia/laravel-sftp) when i installed the package i saw those 3 packages got an uppdate and the error appear