# How do I make a request via postman if the middleware is web?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

So I'm using [snipe-it](https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/) as my backend.
I'm currently making an Android app, and I'm not sure how to realize login method, since there's no API for it.

How am I supposed to approach this? Looking at `request_request`

```
array:2 [
  "username" => "test123"
  "password" => "test123"
]
```

`request_header` has authorization Bearer token.

`snipe-it` is also using OAuth 1.0 I can define Endpoint settings:

- client id,
- name,
- secret

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: "I am not sure where to go from here." 
Straight to the docs. There are basics you should know about API communication between server and client in Laravel framework. Start [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication) and then move to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) page since application is using passport as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay so, after reading a bit I tried oauth/authorize. Grant type: Authorization Code, Auth URL,Callback URL (not sure whats this in snipe-it supposed to be), Access Token URL, Client ID, client secret. Getting this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419216/how-to-fix-invalid-header-value-must-be-a-string-or-array-of-strings-in-larav)

Comment: Just for case try with `composer update && composer du`

Comment: updated composer, still no success though. When I authorize weren't i supposed to send username and email though?

Comment: Email and password. When you send it along with grant type and secret, you should receive token in response. I am telling how passport works.

Comment: Yeah, it seems whatever I send in header. gives this as a response.

Comment: Testing with Postman?

Comment: [Current settings](https://imgur.com/a/fqYkHLz)